# Multiple table rows display in view from one to many related data in laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach

I'm trying to generate a table in Laravel from the array passed from the controller.
The table that I'm going to develop is like this below.

[image]

single "Ask" may have multiple "Issues" and each issue should display related asked data.
But it only generates a number of rows equal to the length of the issue array which is related to the second loop of the code. According to the below table image, it must have 4 rows, but I'm only getting 3 rows.
My codes are below.

> HomeController

```
    $datas = Ask::all();
    $datas->load(['issues']);
    return view('home', compact(['datas']));
```

> Home.blade.php

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($datas as $data)
    @foreach($data->issues as $key=>$issue)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
       <td>{{ $data->id }}</td>
       <td>{{ $data->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $data->created_at->format('H:m:s') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $data->user->name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $data->no_of_bags }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->created_at->format('H:m:s') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->no_of_bags }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->user->name }}</td>
    </tr>

    @endforeach
    @endforeach

 </tbody>
```

foreach loop will terminate after adding issue data to view.
No remaining data related to $data won't displayed.
Can anyone help me to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Can u try? `compact('datas')` or `['datas'=>$datas]`

Comment: your question is not clear..can you add current output and expected output to the question?

Comment: You can try my answer below. But I realized your current code should also produce the same output. Can you check your database if it has the right data. Maybe one of the `Issue` row don't have a `ask_id`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're displaying multiple issues. I suggest that you get the data from the `Issue` model

From your `Issue` model define a relationship there to the `Ask` model.

E.g. put this function on your `Issue.php` model:

```
public function ask()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Ask::class);
}
```

Then on your `HomeController` you can do it like this:

```
$datas = Issue::all();
$datas->load(['ask']);
return view('home', compact(['datas']));
```

Then here on your `Home.blade.php`:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($datas as $key => $issue)
    <tr>
       <td>{{ $key+1 }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->ask->id }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->ask->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->ask->created_at->format('H:m:s') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->ask->user->name }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->ask->no_of_bags }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->created_at->format('H:m:s') }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->no_of_bags }}</td>
       <td>{{ $issue->user->name }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

 </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I am going to display not only the issues but also "Asks" in a single table as shown within the image above. If I retrieve the Issue model data, an array of the data will pass the issue data. But how to display asks data which don't have any issues yet but asks is created already?

Comment: If you have read my answer above, you can see that I defined a relationship function `ask()` in the `Issue` model, then in the controller I eager loaded ask using `$datas->load(['ask']);`. Then in the view I accessed the ask data using `$issue->ask`

Comment: Thanks again, I've already declared the relationship as the same as you mentioned above. Without it, I can't get the related data between the Issue & Ask Models.